# How to insert a node in a BST without using CC_TREE**?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So I have a piece of code, where I have to add a node to a BST. My struct is the following:

```
typedef struct _CC_TREE {
    // Members
    int Value;
    struct _CC_TREE* LChild;
    struct _CC_TREE* RChild;
} CC_TREE;
```

The insert function in the header file looks like this:

```
int TreeInsert(CC_TREE *Tree, int Value);
```

where I have to return the status of the insert.

I tried doing it with another function and add it to the Tree

```
CC_TREE* InsertNewNode(CC_TREE* Tree, int Value)
{
    if (NULL == Tree)
    {
        Tree = (CC_TREE*)malloc(sizeof(CC_TREE));
        Tree->LChild = NULL;
        Tree->RChild = NULL;
        Tree->Value = Value;
        return Tree;
    }
    if (Value <= Tree->Value)
    {
        Tree->LChild = InsertNewNode(Tree->LChild, Value);
    }
    else if (Value >= Tree->Value)
    {
        Tree->RChild = InsertNewNode(Tree->RChild, Value);
    }
    return Tree;
}

int TreeInsert(CC_TREE *Tree, int Value)
{
    CC_UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Tree);
    CC_UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Value);

    Tree = InsertNewNode(Tree, Value);
    return 0;
}
```

I try and construct the tree in my main function:

```
int retVal = -1;
CC_TREE* usedTree = NULL;

retVal = TreeCreate(&usedTree);
if (0 != retVal)
{
    printf("TreeCreate failed!\n");
    goto cleanup;
}

retVal = TreeInsert(usedTree, 20);
if (0 != retVal)
{
    printf("TreeInsert failed!\n");
}
```

but for some reason the `usedTree` remains null. I know that I should use `CC_TREE** Tree` in the insert function, but I am not allowed to.

Comment: Remember that in C function arguments are passed *by value*. That means the values in the call are *copied* into the functions local argument variables. And like all other local variables, their life-time ends when the function returns, and any modifications you make to the variables themselves (like assignment) will be lost. By using the pointer-to operator `&` you can pass a pointer to a variable, and *emulate pass by reference*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for your answer. I feel like I don't really understand where should I put the & in the code.  I get an error message wherever I place it.

Comment: You say that you are not *allowed* to use use `CC_TREE**` in the insert function.  I think you mean that that's an external constraint, yet you also say that you tried it.  Do you perhaps just mean that your attempts so far have failed?

Comment: The only ways to get the top of tree `CC_TREE *` pointer out of `TreeInsert` are to either change the return type to `CC_TREE *`, or to change the parameter type to `CC_TREE **`, or to use a global variable (which is not good if you need more than one tree at a time). Take your pick.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I meant that I know how to do it that way, but not the required way.

Comment: @Pilv Are you allowed to change the return type of `TreeInsert`, or must it return `int`?

Comment: @IanAbbott as I said, I'm not allowed to do any of them.

Comment: @Pilv Then just use `usedTree = InsertNewNode(usedTree, 20);` instead of `retVal = TreeInsert(usedTree, 20);`. :-)

Comment: What is `TreeCreate` supposed to do?

Comment: @IanAbbott the problem with this, is that the Tester won't work than. :(
`TreeCreate` just sets the pointer of the `usedTree` to `NULL`.

Comment: @Pilv Well you are stuck then. If there really is no other allowed way to get a required value out of a function, you can only get it via a global variable (unless that is also disallowed?).

Comment: @IanAbbott I can use global variables, but that way I can not creat more than one Tree. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The insert function in the header file looks like this:
>
> ```
> int TreeInsert(CC_TREE *Tree, int Value);
> ```

If you cannot change the function signature or (ew!) use a global variable to return the root pointer to the caller, then your best alternative is probably to use a dummy tree root.  That would look something like this:

```
int TreeInsert(CC_TREE *Tree, int Value) {
    // Tree points to a dummy root node containing no data.
    // Tree->LChild is the actual root pointer
    CC_TREE *root = Tree->LChild;
    int status = 0;

    // ... perform insertion, possibly resulting in a different value for the
    // root pointer ...

    Tree->LChild = root;
    return status;
}
```

That assumes that the first argument to `TreeInsert()` is always a valid pointer to a `CC_TREE`. If you do this, then **all other tree functions should work analogously.**

You would use that from `main()` like so:

```
    int retVal;
    CC_TREE dummy_tree_root = { 0 };
    
    retVal = TreeInsert(&dummy_tree_root, 42);
```

Note that this approach in effect uses a double pointer via an indirect route (no pun intended).  A `CC_TREE *` is not itself a double pointer, but there are still two levels of indirection between that pointer and either the left or the right child of the node to which it points.

---

Note also that a cleaner way of doing this would involve providing a wrapper structure representing the overall tree instead of using a bare tree node or tree node pointer for the purpose.  The data structures would be something like this:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

struct tree {
    struct node *root;
    // optionally other data, such as size, height, etc.
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. I managed to create my tree. I still have one question. Can I somehow remove or delete the 0 that is in the root of my tree? If so, how?
I have a `int TreeRemove(CC_TREE *Tree, int Value)` function, but if I try to remove the root is the tree, I get a memory error when I try to print the tree. :/

Comment: @Pilv, do you mean the zero value in the *dummy* root?  That's not to be considered in the tree in the first place.  Your tree-print function, like all the others, needs to account for the use of a dummy root node by considering the designated child of the dummy root as the actual root node.